# How to draw multiple annotations in Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit, swift2, mkannotation

I want to draw multiple annotations in map view using MapKit.

Below is the code I have tried. But I see only one annotation. Kindly help.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class Map2ViewController: UIViewController
{     
    var searchController:UISearchController!             
    var annotation:MKAnnotation!                    
    var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!      
    var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!            
    var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!    
    var error:NSError!              // Error if any
    var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!           
    var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!
    var ar: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]?
    @IBOutlet weak var dispAnnotation: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       for a in ar!  //Runs 3 times
       {
                self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(a.latitude), longitude:  Double( a.longitude)  )
                self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
                self.dispAnnotation.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
                self.dispAnnotation.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
                let miles = 10.0
                let scalingFactor =  abs(( cos ( 2*M_PI*self.pointAnnotation.coordinate.latitude/360.0  ) ) )
                var span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0, longitudeDelta: 0)
                span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0
                span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor * 69.0)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.pointAnnotation.coordinate, span)
                [self.dispAnnotation.setRegion(region, animated: true)]

        }
    }
}
```

P.S: The loop is running three times. I have debugged it. I am sending the coordinates from another view controller.

Comment: did you check if the coordinates are different (in the array?)

Comment: Yep: Optional([C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0), C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.0, longitude: -75.0), C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.0, longitude: -87.0)])

Comment: I got it working. The coordinates were wide apart. So I was not able to view all of them. Anyways Thanks. :)